# Firebase can't find Bolt

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

**Update:** Seems to have been fixed somewhere between firebase-tools 3.0.6 and 3.2.0

Recently `firebase deploy` has stopped working because it thinks that Bolt is not installed. It is installed both locally and globally. I've tried updating, uninstalling, manually deleting, reinstalling, and updating again in both location and it always gives the same error:

```
>firebase deploy

Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:

Bolt not installed, run npm install -g firebase-bolt
```

According to npm, firebase 3.2.1, firebase-tools 3.0.6 and firebase-bolt 0.8.1 are installed globally.

Contents of firebase.json:

```
{
  "public": "web",
  "rules": "rules.bolt",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Installed updates for firebase-tools and firebase-bolt, no difference

Comment: Travis, were you able to resolve this issue? I ask, as I'm experiencing exactly the same problem?

Comment: @TheoG No, but it's not happening on another system so I've been deploying from there.

Comment: This is a known issue. Have a look here: `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/205` and test the package mentioned, `npm install -g oscar-b/firebase-tools`

Comment: @TheoG Thanks. Why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. Have a look here:

[firebase-bolt not found on Windows #205](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/205)

and test the package mentioned:

```html
npm install -g oscar-b/firebase-tools
```

Comment: FYI the official firebase-tools is working for me now as of 3.2.0

Comment: @TravisChristian Yes. I've been using the official version of firebase-tools since 3.1.0, which resolved this issue as well.